# fstrim on external SSD drives don't work

Tags: usb, hard-drive, ssd, trim

I have two external USB 3.0 SSD drives from Samsung (one is Model T1, other T3).

I would like to trim them with my Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

While doing that I receive a error message. Here an example:

```
sudo fstrim -v  /media/techo/Samsung_T3
fstrim: /media/techno/Samsung_T3: the discard operation is not supported
```

But the device support the TRIM Command:

```
techno@server:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb |grep -i TRIM
       *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)
```

thx. What do I wrong?

luckyrings

Comment: `fstrim` via USB is not supported as discussed extensively here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2315800

Comment: Irregardless of whether drive supports trim, when connected thru usb you can't run a trim command as it's a SATA command. Case closed...

Comment: Plus - any high quality usb3 ssd should be able to handle garbage collection on it's own.

Comment: I don't think so, that USB generally does not support it. Trim should work via USB Attached SCSI Protocol. Question is if USAP is proper implemented in Linux -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Attached_SCSI

Comment: Maybe fstrim does not support USAP. But the Samsung SSD T3 Portable drive support USAP. While in Windows 8+ it connects with USB Attached SCSI (UASP), enabling advanced functionality like NCQ and TRIM (SCSI Unmap). So what about Linux now?

Comment: I second that. Trim works over USB and should definitely work on linux.
The attitude of the user @doug is really unacceptable.

Comment: According to https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=26014 Western Digital external SSDs *and* HDDs support `UNMAP` which is considered equal to `TRIM` command. Does anybody have any info about if Seagate or other manufacturers support such a thing and if so, which software I can use under Linux? I'm prefer running `fstrim` over having `discard` mount option.

Comment: Looking more about this it seems that the `discard` mount option and `fstrim` both need kernel support for "discard operation" which is only supported for USB-SATA bridges that support SCSI `UNMAP` command and map that to SATA `DISCARD`. Technically it should be possible to speak over USB-UAS-SCSI-SAT-SATA and directly send `DISCARD` as ATA command but Linux kernel does not support that. If you don't need LVM or LUKS, you may be able to use `wiper.sh` (part of `hdparm`) script that uses raw ATA commands.

Comment: @doug disagree. I got an sdcard supporting discard and fstrim works in that case through an usb reader.

Answer (score 4):

USB drives use a USB<>SATA translation via an IC. Different ICs offer slightly more or less SATA command translations. They all translate the SATA commands required for typical disk usage.

So, the hdparm -I (inquiry) command will work. It will tell the user that 'trim' is supported. But that doesn't mean the USB<>SATA translation includes translating the trim command.

It isn't that the inquiry -I command gives incorrect information. The USB<>SATA translation chip just isn't designed to translate the trim command. If enough users complain, something might be done to make the translations more complete.

Comment: I recently learned, after speaking at length with tier-one tech support at Startech, that USB<>SATA and USB<>NVME translation ICs (bridges) run a tiny blob of firmware that can be updated to add more translations.